# Change the image background colour to white?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a set of images which is basically the optical flow of images.

The code for the optical flow was taken from [this post.](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html)
I have used the Dense Optical Flow in OpenCV.

I would like to convert the images from a black background to a white one.

[image]

[image]

This is what I have have now but I feel its not an actual transformation.
Any way I could keep the same amt of info ? Although makiing the 30 to 1 would keep all info same. I feel it has too much extra info (small movement also saved)
any thoughts ?

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
import numpy as np

img1='/home/anilil/Downloads/1.png'
im = cv2.imread(img1,1)
im [im<30]=254

cv2.imshow('abc',im)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Varying the 30 in the `im [im<30]=254` to other values gives several diff images.

## Output images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or you can draw the optical flow on a white image, instead of a black one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following algo:

-convert optical flow to grayscale

-apply inverse threshold on image:

```
cv2.threshold(src,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,mask)
```

-perform weighted addition of src (original image) and mask, using cv2.addWeighted(,,,)